# Error while installing ClickHouse DB Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)

Tags: ubuntu, clickhouse

I followed this link to install ClickHouse DB: https://clickhouse.yandex/#quick-start

I got an error while running this command: sudo apt-get install clickhouse-server-common clickhouse-client -y

Error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
clickhouse-client : Depends: clickhouse-server-base (= 1.1.54236) but it is not going to be installed clickhouse-server-common : Depends: clickhouse-server-base (= 1.1.54236) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Did you follow the install instructions for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial ? Or the default ones for 14.04 ?

Comment: I followed instructions for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

try use following commands

```
apt-get purge -y clickhouse*
apt-get install -y clickhouse-server-common
apt-get install -y clickhouse-client
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package clickhouse-server

Comment: clickhouse-server-common, sorry for mistyping

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clickhouse-server-common : Depends: clickhouse-server-base (= 1.1.54245) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.